# Is there a function in Java to delete indexes which contain 3 data directly in one line?

Tags: java

I want to delete an index that consists of data: name, pass, and phone. At first, I used array.remove(index) method but it only worked if I only have one data. I have tried to use some formula too such as array.remove((index-1)*3) but when I chose show data, it all got messed up. I tried to use looping too but the end result also got messed up. 
Is there any way or logic that I can implement to do that?

[image]

and this is my current code :

```
case 3:
                show(menu);
                System.out.println("Input data number to be deleted: ");
                int index = scan.nextInt();
                //menu.remove(index);
                //menu.removeRange
                for(int i = index-1, j = index ; i < menu.size(); i+=3, j++){
                    menu.remove(i);
                    menu.remove(j);
                    //System.out.println("Data is removed");
                }
//              menu.remove((index-1)*3);
//              menu.remove((index-1)*3+1);
//              menu.remove((index-1)*3+2);
                System.out.println("Data is removed");
                break;

            }
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. You make calls to `menu.remove()` but how `menu` is defined? I assume `menu` is an array, but of what type? why do you try to remove both `i` and `j`? and why using a `for` loop? can't you just remove `index -1`? And one last thing - in case you have 5 items in `menu`, and you delete index 3, what happens to items in index 4 and 5?

Comment: Putting multiple items in a class allows you to delete all the items of the class with one remove.

Comment: the menu is defined as an arraylist with string as data type. i have tried to use index-1 but it is still messed up. If there are 5 items in the menu and i delete index 3, index 4 will be number 3 and index 5 will be number 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit hard to work out what you are trying to do but I'm guessing your issue is that you are removing items from a collection using an index and ignoring the fact that removing one item moves the subsequent items forward.

In other words,

```
collection.remove(3);
collection.remove(3);
collection.remove(3);
```

Removes items that were originally at indices 3, 4 and 5

Comment: [`list.sublist(3,5).clear()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-) is simpler and more explicit in its goal.

Comment: Agree. I was really just trying to point out OP's misunderstanding.